# How to disable windows server 2008 timestamp response

Tags: powershell, timestamp

I was using Rapid7's Nexpose to scan one of our web servers (windows server 2008), and got a vulnerability for timestamp response.

According to Rapid7, timestamp response shall be disabled:
http://www.rapid7.com/db/vulnerabilities/generic-tcp-timestamp

So far I have tried several things:

1. Edit the registry, add a "Tcp1323Opts" key to HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters,  and set it to 0. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938205.aspx
2. Use this command: netsh int tcp set global timestamps=disabled
3. Tried powershell command: Set-netTCPsetting -SettingName InternetCustom -Timestamps disabled 
   (got error: Set-netTCPsetting : The term 'Set-netTCPsetting' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
   operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.)

None of above attempts was successful, after re-scan we still got the same alert.

Rapid7 suggested using a firewall that's capable of blocking it, but we want to know if there is a setting on windows to achieve it.

Thanks.

Comment: This question should be on ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

I will just try to explain why you are having the problem in PowerShell. Cannot speak to Nexpose part...

PowerShell is complaining because you do not have the modules required. Unfortunately, even though you might have the latest PowerShell version, you cannot have them on Windows Server 2008, because Microsoft ties them newer OSes. In other words, to be able to use that command, you would need to be on Windows Server 2012/R2/Windows8/8.1 etc... whichever OS the module that includes that CMDlet was released on.